# theme integration (appwork) in jhispster application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sass, themes, jhipster

I got a theme 'appwork' which I have to integrate in my jhispter application. We are using Angular 6. Within theme, there are many folders like angular-demo, angular-starter etc.. 
I don't know where to start.

Following is the suggestions I got:

1) get the vendor folder within theme/appwork/angular-starter/src 
2) copy the vendor folder at some location in your project (preferably in src/webapp/content)
3) this location should be mentioned in pacakge.json 
e.g. "vendor": "file:src/main/webapp/content/vendor",
4) some changes in vendor.scss

What should be the right way for theme integration. 
 Thanks in Advance

Comment: the best way to integrate themes into your app work is by creating an assets folder within the src folder of your app eg -> *src/assets/vendors/*